# Setting EPSG for OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, openlayers-2

I'm currently trying to create a map based on GeoServer and OpenLayers 3.

My main issue at this point is the coordinate system. I want to use EPSG:25832 (EUREF89 Zone 32).

This is how far I´ve got:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/build/ol.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="http://epsg.io/25832.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() 
{
var euref89z32proj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25832');
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile(
{
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
})

var format = 'image/png';
var linjetest = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        ratio: 1,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/postgre/wms',
        params: {'FORMAT': format,
                'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'postgre:linjetest',
        }
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map1',
layers: [
    linjetest
],
view: new ol.View({
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([10.09, 56.45]),
    maxExtent: new ol.extent.boundingExtent(384015, 5846682, 516991, 5931295),
    zoom: 15
    })
});

var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
        projection: euref89z32proj,
        target: document.getElementById('location'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });
 map.addControl(mousePosition); 
}
```

When I move the mouse around in the map correct coordinates are displayed, but when I use Chromes debugger and look at the the network tab, the URL to GeoServer is based on EPSG:3587 coordinates. Is it possible to configure OpenLayers to use EPSG:25832 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the solution myself. I just needed to add projection to the layer like this:

```
    var linjetest = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        ratio: 1,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/postgre/wms',
        params: {'FORMAT': format,
                'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'postgre:linjetest',
        },
        projection: euref89z32proj
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the projection in view of your map object, as below:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map1',
layers: [
    linjetest
],
view: new ol.View({
projection: euref89z32proj,
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([10.09, 56.45]),
    maxExtent: new ol.extent.boundingExtent(384015, 5846682, 516991, 5931295),
    zoom: 15
    })
});
```

Comment: Before I add projection:euref89z32proj the URL contains SRS=EPSG:3857 and BBOX=1121443.667167902,7647569.032526296,1124983.657040359,7649479.958233425 - After adding projection:euref89z32proj the SRS changes to EPSG:25832 but the BBOX argument is the same so geoserver creates a blank image. Any suggestions to why the BBOX argument isn´t projected rigth?